# how to use time.strptime for a file full of long format date

Tags: python, time, strptime

I am new to python and trying to learn how to read data files. I have a file with time stamps:

```
[2015-07-27T18:01:55.7647616+01:00 2015-07-27T18:01:55.7827840+01:00
 2015-07-27T18:01:55.8142720+01:00 ..., 2015-07-27T18:04:05.3064192+01:00
 2015-07-27T18:04:05.3419776+01:00 2015-07-27T18:04:05.3713280+01:00]
```

I am doing:

```
times = np.loadtxt(filename, dtype=object)
print times[0]
num_records = np.size(times,0)
for date in range(num_records):
    print time.strptime(times[date], "%Y-%b-%dT%H:%M:%S.0000000+00:000")
```

but I get the following error:

```
ValueError: time data '2015-07-27T18:01:55.7647616+01:00' does not match format '%Y-%b-%dT%H:%M:%S.0000000+00:000'
```

I was wondering if somebody can clarify how to match the format for this time format? Finally, I want to convert that date into a number so I can do stats on it. How to do this?

Comment: Well why would you think that `07` would match `%b`, which is *"Month as locale’s abbreviated name"*, for example? [Read the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).

Comment: Are all timezones `+01:00` ?

Comment: @jonrsharpe, you are right, that is a mistake. I could make match the month no problem. The point of the question was how to make the microseconds match, which I could not find in the documentation.

Comment: Many thanks Anand, that was very helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use [`dateutil.parser`](http://dateutil.readthedocs.org/en/latest/parser.html) module for this.

Example/Demo -

```
>>> import dateutil.parser
>>> dateutil.parser.parse('2015-07-27T18:01:55.7647616+01:00')
datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 27, 18, 1, 55, 764761, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, 3600))
```

---

In your code -

```
import dateutil.parser
times = np.loadtxt(filename, dtype=object)
print times[0]
num_records = np.size(times,0)
for date in range(num_records):
    print dateutil.parser.parse(times[date])
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't copy the physical format that the error throws...

Try this:

```
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now()
print now
```

it will print in the format that you want by default.

Answer (score 0):

this is the closest i could get (ignoring the last digit of the mircoseconds and the +01:00)

```
import time

dt = time.strptime('2015-07-27T18:04:05.3419776+01:00'[:26],
                   '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')
print(dt)
```